# How can I hide certain file types from appearing in Aptana Studio's app explorer

Tags: file, types, hide, aptana

I need to prevent a certain file type from appearing in my Aptana Studio's app explorer.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. You can apply the filter to a folder from *App Explorer*, but that will only apply the filter to that folder, and you probably want to apply the filter to the whole project;
2. Apply the filter to the project root from *Project Explorer* which will affect the entire project;

Here's how to apply a filter to either of the above options:

1. right-click the folder/project you want to apply the filter to
2. select `Properties`
3. in the `Resource Filters` section click the `Add` button
4. in the window that pops up choose `Exclude All` in the *Filter Type* section
5. choose one the options from the *Applies To* section (probably Files)
6. tick the `All children (recursive)` option if you want to apply the filter to all children of the chosen folder/project
7. in the *File and Folder attributes* section choose the options that you want (probably `Name` and `matches`
8. In the input field of the *File and Folder attributes* section type the filter that you want

**Example filters:**

- `*~` - hides all files ending with a `~`
- `*.json` - hides all json files

**Note**: These instructions are valid for the current version of Aptana 3.4